# Swagger API consuming json with json validation

Tags: java, json, rest, swagger

I am using Swagger to generate a Restful API:

```
@POST
@Consumes({ "application/json" })
@Produces({ "application/json" })
@io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation(value = "Create a task", notes = "", response = Tasks.class)
@io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses(value = { 
    @io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "created task", response = Tasks.class),
    @io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "task not found", response = Tasks.class),
    @io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "unexpected error", response = Tasks.class) })
public Response createTask(@ApiParam(value = "The task to create" ,required=true ) NewTask newTask)
throws NotFoundException {
    return delegate.createTask(newTask);
}
```

This API accepts json strings and generates java objects from it. This is working quiet well with one exception:
The API accepts any correct formed json string but ignores the content of the json which means i get an object created with default values.

So my question is:
How can i validate the incoming jsonstring ( against a json schema) before the actual java object is generated?

Comment: How do perform the validation against the schema? You can receive your JSON as String, validate it and then create a object from it using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations), for example. But, since you are performing validations, have you considered [Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org/)?

Comment: The problem is, i would have to change the API to receive a json string instead of an object like `public Response createTask(String jsonTask)` in the methods parameters afaik but i would prefer to have the object there if its possible.

Comment: You can [write your own `MessageBodyWriter`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e6851)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to receive a JSON String in your methods and [Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org) is not an option for your validation, you could try a [`MessageBodyWriter<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html).

JAX-RS uses [`MessageBodyWriter<T>`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) to parse incoming requests. Since you want something very specific, consider [writing your own `MessageBodyWriter<T>`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e6851).

See the following example:

```
@Provider
@Produces("application/json")
public class CustomMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
                               Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(MyBean myBean, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
                        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {

        // Deprecated by JAX-RS 2.0
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Object object, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
                        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
                        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
                        OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException {

        // Read the entityStream
        // Perform the validation against your schema
        // Write to the object
    }
}
```

The [`@Provider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html) annotation makes the class to be automatically discovered by the JAX-RS runtime during a provider scanning phase.

Comment: One question: I am using Swagger which brings its own MessageBodyWriter. [link](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-jaxrs/src/main/java/io/swagger/jaxrs/listing/SwaggerSerializers.java) Would i need to change the swagger source? Or is there another way i could force the use of my own implementation (without reflection)?

Comment: @Gobliins Annotating your `MessageBodyWriter` with `@Provider` or [registering it to your `Application`or `ResourceConfig` class](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#environmenmt.appmodel) should be enough to it be recognized by Jersey/JAX-RS.

Comment: Err.. wouldn't i need the other way (DeSerializer)? Since the i want to verify an incoming json before mapping it to the model and not writing a model in a json stream?

Comment: @Gobliins Jersey/JAX-RS already provide a [`MessageBodyReader<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) for JSON. You can write your own if the provided one doesn't fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [swagger-request-validator](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator) having several adapters for various frameworks, e.g.: [Spring Web MVC](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator/src/master/swagger-request-validator-springmvc/)

It is capable of validating requests and / or responses against Swagger / OpenAPI 2 or OpenAPI 3 schemes.

See here: [Validating JSON messages against Swagger definition in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58215869/8225898) for a more detailed answer.