# Validating JSON messages against Swagger definition in Java

Tags: java, json, rest, validation, swagger

I created a REST API using a Swagger definition, now I need to validate incoming messages using that swagger schema. I found several solutions however all of them rely on some specific use case. The closest to what I need is [this](http://wilddiary.com/validate-json-against-schema-in-java/) and true to it's description it works well with provided json schema, however when I deliver much more complex swagger definition, it just marks everything as valid. My question is. Is there any better, more complete or competent solution, library perhaps, that would natively validate given JSON messages against Swagger definition? I need this because I'm implementing WSO2 API REST solution and this would greatly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [swagger-request-validator](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator) having several adapters for various frameworks, e.g.: [Spring Web MVC](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator/src/master/swagger-request-validator-springmvc/)

It is capable of validating requests and / or responses against Swagger / OpenAPI 2 or OpenAPI 3 schemes.

It doesn't simply validate the defined JSON body. It validates the rest of the request, too, like path (variables), headers, etc.

The validator is capable of i18n.

Up until now the most complete validation against Swagger and OpenAPI in Java.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at my answer here with a solution for this:

[Validating json payload against swagger file - json-schema-validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53374810/validating-json-payload-against-swagger-file-json-schema-validator/58215491#58215491)

It's based on using the library: https://github.com/bjansen/swagger-schema-validator. It allows to check your json against the definitions contained in the swagger schema.

```
try (InputStream inputStream = schemaLocation.getInputStream()) {
            SwaggerValidator validator = SwaggerValidator.forJsonSchema(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            ProcessingReport report = validator.validate(message, "/definitions/Pet");
            return report.isSuccess();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("IOException", e);
            return false;
        } catch (ProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
```